# how to Calculate this series

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int fact(int number)
{
  unsigned long long int p = 1;
  if (number == 0) {
    return p;
  }
  for (int i = 1; number >= i; i++) {
    p = p * i;
  }
  return p;
}

int main()
{
  long long int  a, x, sum = 0, result;
  int  n ;
  cin >> a;
  cin >> x;
  cin >> n;
  for (int k = 0; n >= k; k++) {
    result = fact(n) / (fact(k) * fact(n - k));
    sum = sum + (result * pow(x, k) * pow(a, n - k));
  }
  cout << sum;
  return 0;
}
```

I want to calculate this series

[image: The series]

So I considered the `long long int sum`, but the `sum` number sometimes gets too big. What can I do to save the sum number without using library?

Comment: Please paste images into your code.  Firewalls prevent access to links.

Comment: You can use all the `long long`s you want, but it's not going to help when the function returns an `int` anyway. Regardless, it won't be long before that series goes beyond the limits of a 64-bit int. Using the limits, where `a=10^9`, `n=10`, `k=0`, we already have 10^90 in the equation.

Comment: Nothing. You either use a library or you create your own.

Comment: *What can I do to save the sum number without using library?* -- Use your math skills to rearrange that formula so that the numbers used in the calculations can fit into a 64-bit integer.  You will quickly learn that many times, you can't just plop down a formula you see in a math book straight into a computer program.  Round-off error, large numbers, etc. requires a rework of the formula in such a way where these issues are not an issue.

Comment: Do you need the exact result to every decimal place? The easiest thing would be to used floating point (i.e., `double` variables).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest to use binomial theorem -- what you are computing is just `pow(x+a, n)`

If you want to do this through series, do not compute the binomial coefficient using factorials but something like this

```
int bin_coeff(int n, int k){
    int lim = k > n/2 ? k : n - k;
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > lim; i--){
        sum *= i;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < (n - lim + 1); i++){
        sum /= i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```